# Android main thread blocking WebView thread

Tags: javascript, java, android, multithreading, webview

I've been working on a problem with doing a synchronous call to JavaScript in a `WebView` (with a return value) and trying to narrow down the where and why of why it's not working. It seems to be that the `WebView` thread is blocking while the main thread is waiting for a response from it -- which shouldn't be the case since the`WebView` runs on a separate thread.

I've put together this small sample that demonstrates it (I hope) fairly clearly:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">

    <WebView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String TAG = "MyActivity";

    private WebView webView;
    private JSInterface JS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        JS = new JSInterface();

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JS, JS.getInterfaceName());

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 Log.d(TAG, JS.getEval("test()"));
             }
         });

        webView.loadData("<script>function test() {JSInterface.log(\"returning Success\"); return 'Success';}</script>Test", "text/html", "UTF-8");
    }


    private class JSInterface {

        private static final String TAG = "JSInterface";

        private final String interfaceName = "JSInterface";
        private CountDownLatch latch;
        private String returnValue;

        public JSInterface() {
        }

        public String getInterfaceName() {
            return interfaceName;
        }

        // JS-side functions can call JSInterface.log() to log to logcat

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void log(String str) {
            // log() gets called from Javascript
            Log.i(TAG, str);
        }

        // JS-side functions will indirectly call setValue() via getEval()'s try block, below

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void setValue(String value) {
            // setValue() receives the value from Javascript
            Log.d(TAG, "setValue(): " + value);
            returnValue = value;
            latch.countDown();
        }

        // getEval() is for when you need to evaluate JS code and get the return value back

        public String getEval(String js) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getEval(): " + js);
            returnValue = null;
            latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            final String code = interfaceName
                    + ".setValue(function(){try{return " + js
                    + "+\"\";}catch(js_eval_err){return '';}}());";
            Log.d(TAG, "getEval(): " + code);

            // It doesn't actually matter which one we use; neither works:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
                webView.evaluateJavascript(code, null);
            else
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + code);

            // The problem is that latch.await() appears to block, not allowing the JavaBridge
            // thread to run -- i.e., to call setValue() and therefore latch.countDown() --
            // so latch.await() always runs until it times out and getEval() returns ""

            try {
                // Set a 4 second timeout for the worst/longest possible case
                latch.await(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "InterruptedException");
            }
            if (returnValue == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "getEval(): Timed out waiting for response");
                returnValue = "";
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "getEval() = " + returnValue);
            return returnValue;
        }

        // eval() is for when you need to run some JS code and don't care about any return value

        public void eval(String js) {
            // No return value
            Log.d(TAG, "eval(): " + js);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
                webView.evaluateJavascript(js, null);
            else
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + js);
        }
    }
}
```

When running, the following results:

```
Emulator Nexus 5 API 23:

05-25 13:34:46.222 16073-16073/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: getEval(): test()
05-25 13:34:50.224 16073-16073/com.example.myapp I/JSInterface: getEval(): Timed out waiting for response
05-25 13:34:50.224 16073-16073/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: getEval() = 
05-25 13:34:50.225 16073-16073/com.example.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 239 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-25 13:34:50.235 16073-16150/com.example.myapp I/JSInterface: returning Success
05-25 13:34:50.237 16073-16150/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: setValue(): Success
```

*(16073 is 'main'; 16150 is 'JavaBridge')*

As you can see, the main thread times out waiting for the`WebView` to call `setValue()`, which it doesn't until `latch.await()` has timed out and main thread execution has continued.

Interestingly, trying with an earlier API level:

```
Emulator Nexus S API 14:

05-25 13:37:15.225 19458-19458/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: getEval(): test()
05-25 13:37:15.235 19458-19543/com.example.myapp I/JSInterface: returning Success
05-25 13:37:15.235 19458-19543/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: setValue(): Success
05-25 13:37:15.235 19458-19458/com.example.myapp D/JSInterface: getEval() = Success
05-25 13:37:15.235 19458-19458/com.example.myapp D/MyActivity: Success
```

*(19458 is 'main'; 19543 is 'JavaBridge')*

Things work correctly in sequence, with `getEval()` causing the `WebView` to call `setValue()`, which then exits `latch.await()` before it times out (as you'd expect/hope).

(I've also tried with an even earlier API level, but things crash out due to what may be, as I understand it, an emulator-only bug in 2.3.3 that never got fixed.)

So I'm at a bit of a loss. In digging around, this seems like the correct approach to doing things. It certainly *seems* like the correct approach because it works properly on API level 14. But then it's failing on later versions — and I've tested on 5.1 and 6.0 without success.

Comment: did you get it working? In my case, it works for api 23, but doesn't work for api 21. I am also stuck with same problem.

Comment: I actually rewrote it quite significantly, starting pretty much from scratch. I ended up having to change my approach on how I was doing things because I was having issues. But I do recall running into a problem that (if I recall) only manifested with certain APIs and/or emulator images.

Answer (score 1):

Look more about migration WebView with Android 4.4. 
[See description on Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) I think you need to use another method for funning your JS action.

For example, base on that doc - [Running JS Async](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)) Asynchronously evaluates JavaScript in the context of the currently displayed page. If non-null, |resultCallback| will be invoked with any result returned from that execution. This method must be called on the UI thread and the callback will be made on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. However, I am specifically *not* using a callback for evaluateJavascript() because that would make it async. And while all WebView calls must be made on the UI thread, as you can see above, the call *back* from JS via setValue() is clearly coming on a different thread (i.e., JavaBridge). I still don't get why the main UI thread blocks the JavaBridge thread once the (async) evaluateJavascript() or loadUrl() call has been made. I haven't seen any explanation yet as to why the main UI thread can't wait (latch, semaphore, etc.) while JavaBridge executes.

Comment: @KT_ I have checked your code in Nexus-4 device with Android version 5.1.1 and its working.